# Efficient parallel 3D rotation

Tags: python, 3d, parallel-processing, rotation

I have a large (1000x1000x5000) 3D numpy array upon which I need to perform many 3D rotations and then compute an asymmetric distance transform. The distance transform is trivially parallelizable, but I need a way to also perform the rotation itself using a computing cluster (which doesn't have so much [e.g. 2GB] memory/core). What's a good strategy to efficiently exploit the computing cluster? (it does not have any GPUs or other specialized hardware for that matter).
And yes, I need the rotated volume - meaning that I cannot just simply relabel the coordinates as the asymmetric distance transform will overwrite the dataset several times.
The software I'm using on the cluster: python3.4.2 with scipy, numpy and mpi4py.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 3D rotation? Since your dataset does not have the right shape to represent points in 3D space. Also `np.zeros((1000, 1000, 5000), dtype='float64')`  is 38 GB, so if you have 2GB per core, you would need ~40cores just to hold the input and output arrays, let alone perform operations. Realistically, you would probably need at least 128cores, considering temporary arrays, for this task. How many cores per node do you have?

Comment: In scipy you have scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate - which I would like to have performed in parallel on a cluster. Since I have access to a supercomputer, 128 cores is tractable. What I don't have is much experience in how to set up the task efficiently, and was wondering wether there is some "cookbook" for parallel matrix operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do matrix operations (e.g. a rotation that you could express as a matrix multiplication) in parallel on a cluster,  what I would do is.

1. Compile numpy with a multi-threaded BLAS (e.g. OpenBLAS) so the matrix multiplication is multi-threaded on a node. The advantage is that you know this has been extensively tested and optimized, and you don't need to worry about parallel scaling.
2. Assuming that the machine has, say 32 cores per node (i.e. 2*32=64 GB of RAM in total). I would run ~4 MPI task per node with 8 threads / MPI task (so the available RAM / task is 16 GB, thus removing the low RAM constraints).
3. Do a domain decomposition of your array among MPI tasks. For instance, [this code (see `_mprotate` function)](https://paulmueller.github.io/ODTbrain/_modules/odtbrain/_Back_3D.html) does a computation of rotations with `scipy.ndimage` using `multiprocessing`, you could do something similar but with `mpi4py`.

Although the problem is that, unless I'm mistaken,  `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` does not use matrix operations with BLAS, and is a pure C implementation that in the end calls the [`NI_GeometricTransform`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/d1203c280a8661536d64f17e6a90d7ef000302d5/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_interpolation.c#L358) function. So, unless you use a different algorithm, the above approach won't work. You will then have to run as many MPI tasks as you have cores, and do the domain decomposition among them (see `mpi4py` tutorials).

*This does not fully answer your question but hope it helps.*